# How to make "dzil test" pass command line arguments to Makefile.PL?

Tags: perl, dist-zilla

For one of my XS based Perl modules that depends on a C library, I use [`Dist::Zilla`](https://metacpan.org/module/Dist::Zilla) together with with the [`MakeMaker::Awesome`](https://metacpan.org/module/Dist::Zilla::Plugin::MakeMaker::Awesome) plugin to create my `Makefile.PL`.

In order to pass options to `Makefile.PL` (especially `INC` and `LIBS`), I used to set the `PERL_MM_OPT` environment variable which worked fine so far.

Now I want to use [`Devel::CheckLib`](https://metacpan.org/module/Devel::CheckLib) to check for the presence of the C library. `Devel::CheckLib` also supports `INC` and `LIBS` when supplied via the command line, but it doesn't read these options from `PERL_MM_OPT`.

How can I make `dzil test` pass command line arguments to `Makefile.PL`?

From a quick look at [the source of the `MakeMaker::Runner` plugin](https://metacpan.org/source/RJBS/Dist-Zilla-5.031/lib/Dist/Zilla/Plugin/MakeMaker/Runner.pm#L38) this doesn't seem to be supported. Is there another work-around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing arguments to `Makefile.PL` simply isn't supported by `dzil` and probably will never be. As a work-around, I add the contents of `PERL_MM_OPT` to a local copy of `@ARGV` before calling into `Devel::CheckLib`:

```
{
    local @ARGV;
    unshift(@ARGV, ExtUtils::MakeMaker::_shellwords($ENV{PERL_MM_OPT} || ''));
    check_lib_or_exit(...);
}
```

Ugly, but works.